# How does this reverseBytes method work?

Tags: c, byte, bit, bit-shift

I was looking at this function online and am wondering how it works:

```
   /*
    * reverseBytes - reverse bytes
    *   Example: reverseBytes(0x12345678) = 0x78563412
    *   Legal ops: ! ~ & ^ | + << >>
    */
    int reverseBytes(int x)
    {
        int newbyte0 = (x >> 24) & 0xff;
        int newbyte1 = (x >> 8) & 0xff00;
        int newbyte2 = (x << 8) & 0xff0000;
        int newbyte3 = x << 24;

        return newbyte0 | newbyte1 | newbyte2 | newbyte3;
    }
```

Here's what I think I understand:

- `0xff`, `0xff00`, and `0xff0000` in binary are `1111 1111`, `1111 1111 0000 0000`, and `1111 1111 0000 0000 0000 0000` respectively
- The method creates four new bytes with masks (`0xff`, etc), and then adds their values together using the `|` operator

I really don't get how this reverses the bytes though. I would appreciate a detailed explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code assumes a 32 bit integer and 8 bit bytes. A 32 bit integer is made up of 4 bytes:
Let's say these 4 bytes are laid out in memory like so:

```
+---------------------------------+
|Byte 4 | Byte 3 | Byte 2 | Byte 1|
+---------------------------------+
```

This could relate to the [Endianess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of a given CPU type. When interpreting an integer that is made up of several bytes, some CPU families will treat the leftmost byte, the one with a lower memory address as the most significant byte of the integer - such CPUs are called big endian. Other CPUs will do the reverse, they will treat the rightmost byte within an integer , the byte with the largest memory address as the most significant byte - little endian CPUs. So your functions convert an integer from one endian to another.

```
int newbyte0 = (x >> 24) & 0xff;
```

This takes the integer (the 4 bytes) depicted above, shifts it 24 bits to the right, and masks off everything but the lower 8 bits, newbyte0 looks like this now, where Byte 4 is the original Byte 4 of `x` and the other 3 bytes have all bits set to zero.

```
+---------------------------------+
|  0    |  0    |   0    | Byte 4 |
+---------------------------------+
```

Similarely

```
 int newbyte1 = (x >> 8) & 0xff00;
```

Shifts the bits 8 bits to the right, and masks off everything but the 8 bits in the 2. byte from the left. The result looks like this with, with only Byte 3 remaining of the original value of `x`

```
+---------------------------------+
|  0    |  0    |  Byte 3 |   0   |
+---------------------------------+
```

The 2 leftmost bytes are handled similarly, just `x` is shifted left to accomplish the same thing.

Finally you have

```
 newbyte0 | newbyte1 | newbyte2 | newbyte3;
```

Which combines all the integers you created above, each with only 8 bits remaining from the original `x`. Do a bitwise `or` of them, and you end up with

```
+---------------------------------+
|Byte 1 | Byte 2 | Byte 3 | Byte 4|
+---------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 int newbyte0 = (x >> 24) & 0xff;
```

Shifts the number 24 bits to the right, so that the left-most byte will now be the right-most byte. It then uses a mask (`0xff`) to zero out the rest of the bytes, which is redundant as the shift will have zeroed them anyways, so the mask can be omitted.

```
int newbyte1 = (x >> 8) & 0xff00;
```

Shifts the number 8 bits to the right, so that the second byte from the left is now the second byte from the right, and the rest of the bytes are zeroed out with a mask.

```
int newbyte2 = (x << 8) & 0xff0000;
```

Shifts the number 8 bits to the left this time - essentially the same thing as the last line, only now the second byte from the right becomes the second byte from the left.

```
int newbyte3 = x << 24;
```

The same as the first line (this time the redundant mask really is omitted) - the right-most byte becomes the left-most byte.

```
return newbyte0 | newbyte1 | newbyte2 | newbyte3;
```

And finally you just `OR` all the bytes to finish the reversal.

You can actually follow this process step-by-step in code by using `printf("%x", newbyte)` to print each of the bytes - the `%x` format allows you to print in hexadecimal.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume for 32 bit system you have passed `0x12345678` to the function.

```
 int newbyte0 = (x >> 24) & 0xff;     //will be 0x00000012
 int newbyte1 = (x >> 8) & 0xff00;    //will be 0x00003400
 int newbyte2 = (x << 8) & 0xff0000;  //will be 0x00560000
 int newbyte3 = x << 24;              //will be 0x78000000

return newbyte0 | newbyte1 | newbyte2 | newbyte3; will be 0x78563412
```

Answer (score 0):

This function just shift byte to the right position in an integer and than OR all of them together. 
For example x is 0xAABBCCDD:
For the first byte we shift all byte to the right, so we have 0x00000000AA & 0xFF which is 0xAA.

For the second byte we have 0x00AABBCC & 0xFF00 which is 0x0000BB00

And so on. 
We just shift bits to the right position and erase all other bits.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your understands the code correctly, but of course it assumes int as 32 bits value.

```
    int newbyte0 = (x >> 24) & 0xff; // Shift the bits 24~31 to 0~7
    int newbyte1 = (x >> 8) & 0xff00; // Shift the bits 16~23 to 8~15
    int newbyte2 = (x << 8) & 0xff0000; // Shifts bit bits 8~15 to 16~23
    int newbyte3 = x << 24; // Shift bits 0~7 to 24~31

    return newbyte0 | newbyte1 | newbyte2 | newbyte3; // Join all the bits
```